# Интерфейсы - сходство их проблем с проблемами Абстрактных классов

Tags: java

Как известно, отличие интерфейсов от абстрактных классов в возможностях создания переменных(только final static у интерфейса) и в возможности множественного наследования интерфейсов.
Обновление Java 8 почти стерло грань, оставив лишь выше описанные ограничения. Значит ли это, что теперь интерфейсы с default методами имеют те же болячки, что и классы?

> P.S.: Вот список болячек:
>
> Опасности использования наследования:
>
> 1. Мы можем не знать, что переписываемый метод может вызываться в другом методе суперкласса, что приводит к ошибкам в вычислениях. Ярким
>      примером является создание счетчика вызовов добавления элементов в
>      HashSet -
>
>    ```
>     class InstrumentedHashSet extends HashSet{
>      private int addCount = 0;
>      //Пропуск конструктора. Перейдем к сути
>      //…
>      public boolean add(Object o){
>           addCount++;
>           super.add(o);
>       }
>       public boolean addAll(Collection c){
>           addCount+=c.size();
>           super.addAll(c);
>       }  
>       //… Другие методы
>     }
>    ```
>
>    InstrumentedHashSet-а, то мы добавляем размер коллекции и вызываем
>      метод addAll() HashSet, который содержит внутри метод add(). Он, в
>      свою очередь, вызывает переписанный метод! В итоге нам отдадут число,
>      которое в 2 раза больше ожидаемого. Такое «использование самого себя»
>      является деталью реализации, и нет гарантии, что она не поменяется от
>      одной версии к другой. Это можно поменять, просто поставив цикл с
>      вызовом add(), но это является повторением кода, и вообще - можно
>      что-то упустить. Этот вариант сложен, трудоемок и подвержен ошибкам.
> 2. Суперкласс в новой версии может обзавестись некоторыми методами. Предположим, что у нас есть система безопасности. У нас есть подкласс,
>      который контролирует добавление новых элементов(переопределяет методы,
>      в них проверяет соответствие элементов каким-то нормам). Выходит новый
>      метод, который имеет некую строку, которая просто добавляет строку
>      напрямую. Итог: защита имеет брешь, систему можно взломать.
> 3. Если суперкласс заимеет метод, который есть в одном из подклассов, то, в лучшем случае, когда аргументы не совпадают, то программа просто
>      не скомпилируется. В худшем случае мы просто будем получать неверный
>      результат, не зная где ошибка.
> 4. Все дефекты суперкласса перейдут в API подкласса, в то время как композиция позволяет разработать новый API, который скрывает эти
>      недостатки. Поэтому вы обязаны хорошо продумать реализацию, структуру,
>      так как есть только один шанс что-то изменить. Нужно пробовать разные
>      варианты структур, реализаций.
>
> `//единственная болячка, которая не переходит:`
>
> 5. Мы можем случайно наследовать класс, который вообще для этого не заточен, который либо не документирован для наследования, либо вообще
>      не документирован. Решение — делать такие классы final, чтобы от него
>      нельзя было наследоваться. Это, кстати, даст небольшой прирост в
>      скорости.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93793/discussion-on-question-by-miron-------).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот исчерпывающий ответ на этот вопрос(подредактированно мной под новый лад)(источник - http://javapitstop.com/article/java-interfaces/):

В этом важном абзаце я оттеню крайне важную мысль, если кто-то, случайно, не обратил на неё внимания. Итак, осталась ли разница между интерфейсом и абстрактным классом после того, как у интерфейса появилась возможность определять методы? Да. Разница осталась. И довольно существенная.

Суть её в том, что интерфейс по прежнему не имеет полей (fields). Ни полей класса (статических), ни полей объекта (экземпляров класса). Исключительно и только константы. А значит — никакой метод интерфейса не может что-то сохранить между своими вызовами. Говоря формально — у интерфейса по прежнему нет состояний. Методы интерфейса могут хранить лишь логику работы алгоритма. Интерфейс по прежнему является концептуально другой сущностью языка. И, в силу описанных выше ограничений, не способен сломать ранее реализованную логику. Не взирая на новые возможности. Что хорошо и важно.

Когда вы в классе наследнике переопределяете метод, обозначенный в интерфейсе как default, вы уже не должны употреблять модификатор default. И этот, переопределённый в классе метод, является полноценным методом класса, имеющим право изменять значения переменных класса/объекта. В отличие от своего интерфейсного варианта.

Подытожим. Итак, когда мы реализуем/расширяем интерфейс, содержащий методы с модификатором default у нас есть следующие варианты обращения с каждым из таких методов:

- Использовать метод предка как есть
- Переопределить (override — реализовать заново) метод
- Переобъявить метод как абстрактный, тем самым затребовав его реализацию потомком

Множественное наследование.

Ещё один интересный момент, возникающий с появлением возможности методов интерфейса содержать программный код.

Любой Java класс может наследовать другой Java класс. Но всего один! А вот унаследовать и реализовать интерфейсов Java класс может сколько угодно. Интерфейс также может расширять много интерфейсов. Поскольку ранее интерфейсы не содержали кода, то никаких проблем не возникало. Теперь, как мы уже знаем, начиная с Java 8 интерфейсы могут содержать методы с кодом (static и default методы). Другими словами — появилось то, что уже можно назвать множественным наследованием. И это значит, что ситуация приобрела и проблемы, привносимые этим множественным наследованием(те болячки, которые были перечислены в вопросе).

Отличие абстрактного класса от интерфейса

В конце, для логической точки, хотелось бы коротко ответить на сакральный вопрос отличия интерфейса от абстрактного класса с учётом последних веяний от Java 8 и Java 9:

- У абстрактного класса могут быть конструкторы.
- У абстрактного класса помимо констант могут быть поля (уровня класса или объекта).
- У абстрактного класса методы могут изменять значения полей класса/объекта. По умному - класс может иметь состояния.